# jQuery Validation 1.9 does not work in IE9

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

Does anybody have a siilar problem. I tried combining jQuery 1.5.2, 1.6.1, 1.7.1 and in Firefox and Chrome all works fine but IE9 does not.

Her is the jQuery code. It is simple form for login and if textboxes for username and password are empty it should fire required validation

in firefox and chrome if I leave username and password field empty and press button login the validation fires and labels This field is required appears on the right side of both textboxes. In IE it just bypasses this and goes to controller.

In IE I changed browser mode to IE8, IE7 and it works OK. Just IE9 does not.

```
<form id="frmLogin" method="post" action="">
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)          
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { id = "Email" })
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { id = "Password" })
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<button type="submit">Continue</button>              
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var email = $('#Email');
    var password = $('#Password');

    password.val('');

    if (email.val() == '')
        email.focus();
    else
        password.focus();
});

$().ready(function () {
    $.validator.addMethod('alphaNumeric', function (value) {
        return /^([a-zA-ZčČšŠžŽćĆđĐ0-9]+)?$/.test(value);
    }, "@ValidationMessages.AlphaNumeric");

    $("#frmLogin").validate({
        rules: {
            Email: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                minlength: 5,
                maxlength: 50
            },
            Password: {
                required: true,
                alphaNumeric: true,
                minlength: 6,
                maxlength: 20
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I've got the same issue... did you ever find a solution?  I was told to update jQuery and validate, but the combinations of jq1.4 or 1.7 with val1.6-1.9 have proved unsuccessful.

Comment: no...still does not work and have not found any solution. Probably the only way is to use older versions...funny though how community does not fix such a "minor" problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting 
 var email = $('#Email'); 
 var password = $('#Password');

to

var email = $('#Email').val();
var password = $('#Password').val();

The variables may not convert to jquery objects, but looking for simple values instead.

Comment: The problem is that even simple jQuery validation does not work. For example two required fields and the validation does not work in IE 9. It must be problem in IE9 or jQuery or jQuery validation plugin

Comment: Another thing is to check out the source of the html. IE renders some html elements different than other browsers. jQurey was made to read/modify simple html elements that are formatted correct. Ex. make sure elements have matching closing tags, the proper number of quotations around id or name properties. Sever side .NET MVC helpers can render elements wrong on occasion.

Comment: I installed Windows 8 with VS 2012 and again. The same issue in IE 10 works. If i change Browser mode to IE 9 still does not work